# Can $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{p}\ln^{q}(x+a)}{(x+a)^{b}}dx$ be expressed in a simple form?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I was browsing the book ***Irresistible Integrals*** and found this gem, at page 97,
$$
\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\ln^{k}(x)dx=\frac{(-1)^{k}k!}{(n+1)^{k+1}}
$$
that resembles a previous question of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363565/finding-the-general-form-for-int-fracxp-lnqxaxabdx). So, I'm wondering if, somehow, one could find such a similarly simple expression for
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{p}\ln^{q}(x+a)}{(x+a)^{b}}dx
$$
So, the question is, can someone find such expression?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:**
This is just to clarify the reason I think the present question is different from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363565/finding-the-general-form-for-int-fracxp-lnqxaxabdx) one. I'm looking for a simpler expression, someting like a fraction in the line of $\frac{k!}{(n+1)^{k+1}}$, mayby a litle bit mone complicated. This contrasts with the **double sum** that results from the solution given by Robert Israel.

So what I'm looking for is a simpler expression. I already have an answer, but I'd like to have a simpler one.

---

**EDIT 2**
Here are the constraints of the problem: $p, q \in \mathbb{N}$, $a \in \mathbb{N_{>0}}$ and $b \in \mathbb{Q_{>0}}$.

Comment: I hope my reference still could be of help here. See. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911283/generalized-logarithmic-integral-reference-request/911339#911339

Comment: wasn't your question alreeady answered? Or if you know the result but would like to know if there is a more explicit formula than @RobertIsrael gave, you should say so! :)

Comment: @Ant, yes my question was already answered, but what I'm looking for is something more simple, something like the result of the first integral in this post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the general form for $\int\frac{x^{p}\ln^{q}(x+a)}{(x+a)^{b}}dx$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363565/finding-the-general-form-for-int-fracxp-lnqxaxabdx)

Comment: @Dr. MV, see my edit.

Comment: @Neves Are there any constraints on the parameters? E.g., may we assume integer exponents?

Comment: @David H, yes there are constraints, $p, q \in \mathbb{N}$, $a \in \mathbb{N_{>0}}$ and $b \in \mathbb{Q_{>0}}$.

Comment: I don't think you will get anything better than in the answer to your previous question. Especially for non-integer $b$. So what's the point of this question?